# How to store char as variables in pascal and other questions

Tags: char, pascal

I am very new to programming and I'm trying to make a program (in Pascal) that stores a letter chosen by the user several times, like this:

```
sizes: set of char = ['a' .. 'f'];

Nings: integer = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5;

writeln ('Choose the number of pizzas (min:1 e max:5)');

read (Nings);

while (Nings => 1) do

    Begin

        writeln ('a- extra small');

        writeln ('b- small');

        writeln ('c- regular');

        writeln ('d- medium');

        writeln ('e- large');

        writeln ('f- extra large');

        read (sizes);

        Nings:= Nings-1;

    End;
```

As I said I'm very new at this, and I wanted to store a number of letters equal to the number of pizzas chosen, and I don't know how. (This is just a piece of the code.) Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to review what a `set` type is. Internally a set consists of single bits for each value the set can hold. Your set of char can only keep track of one 'a', one 'b', etc ('a' is, or is not, in the set; 'b' is, or is not, in the set ...).

Since you need to keep track of up to five pizzas, each one of any of the six sizes you offer, you need to store the size information in an array, say `array[1..5] of char`. You can use the `Nings` variable as index to the `sizes` array, like `read(sizes[Nings])` in the while loop.

Btw, variables of limited range are declared in one of two ways:

1) as a type that declares the values and then a variable of that type:

```
type
  TNings = 1..5;
var
  Nings: TNings;
```

2) using numeric or character subranges as type in the variable declaration:

```
  Nings: 1..5
```